# Re-map Ctrl+S to File.Save in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I was messing around with the keyboard shortcuts the other day, and by mistake saved a setting that overrides the default behavior for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> - I soon found out this wasn't what I wanted (obviously), but now I can't find how to reset it.

I have looked in Tools->Options...->Keyboard for "File.Save" and "File.Save[whatever]", but neither seems to be the command I'm looking for. Where do I set the shortcut for just a regular save operation?

***Note:*** Just resetting everything to default isn't an option, since I have made up too many custom commands to want to re-do them all over again. I need to reset **this one option only**.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you are in the right place. It should be:
`File.SaveSelectedItem`s (Ctrl +S (Global))

Instead of looking for it, perhaps add a new shortcut doing the same thing (because you know you have lost your settings anyway.)

1) Use new shortcut in - Select 'Text Editor' from the drop down.
2) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for assigning the shortcut to it
3) Hit 'Assign'

This should recreate your shortcut for you.

Comment: Brilliant! Turns out I had assigned it to File.SaveSelection rather than File.SaveSelectedItems, but when I re-assigned it worked. Thanks!

Comment: for me had to set it to File.SaveSelectedItems as the answer suggests